# Showing URL in the button title

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have 4 categories, 2 subcategories and two button as shown below.

https://jsfiddle.net/mboz45fv/15/

[image]

So, here is what I am trying to achieve.

There are two buttons and 4 category buttons, 2 sub category buttons.
By default, it will say `Button 1` and `Button 2`.

When `cat_B` button is clicked (Image-A), the user will be directed to `.com/cat_B` page (Image-B). I want to show the `cat_B` in the title of the `button 1` as shown in the picture.

Each categories will have two sub-categories.
When `sub_cat_B` is clicked, the user will be redirected to `.com/cat_b/sub_cat_b`. I would like the title of the `button 2` to be `sub_cat_B` when they are in that page.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If `.com/cat_B` is a new page then you have a page to work with. Change the HTML on the new page.

Comment: I can certainly do that. I just didn't want to have redundancy by repeating same code over and over again. Thanks though.

Comment: This is where you want a template system... the choices there are wide and varied and most commonly handled server side.

Comment: Would you recommend a good template system for this case? I have never dealt with a template system and so I am not sure where to start from. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would build each page with seperate buttons already showing the host page URl, precisely as you describe, i presume there is a reason why not. if you do want to set a buttons text with jquery you could use:

```
$("#cat_b").html('.com/cat_b');
```

If reduced code is what youre after then assuming you are using buttons not inputs and have structured your button something like:

```
<button id="cat_b" class="butt" onclick="location.href='.com/cat_b'">button</button>
```

You could use @rkho's approach but grab the url directly from the buttons own onclick attribute, also triggering this by class should reduce the amount of code:

```
$('.butt').click(function(){
 var link=$(this).attr('onclick');
 var buttonText = link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 $("#cat_b").html(buttonText)
 })
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out. I actually have over 30 categories and didn't want to repeat the same code. =) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We're going to get the URL in the window first. Let's store it in a variable called `id`:

```
var id = window.location.href
```

Then, let's grab everything to the right of that last slash:

```
var buttonText = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Now, you can set your specific button (let's assume you've labeled it with a class 'button'):

```
$(".button").text(buttonText);
```